# ssh: Permission denied, please try again

Tags: ssh, permissions

I have just installed raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 1 Model B, and I am trying to connect it via ssh.

I enabled 'ssh' via 'raspi-config', changed the password of 'pi' user from the default to another new one, and I tried from another PC:

```
# ssh pi@192.168.1.100
```

But I get this error message:

```
pi@192.168.1.100's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

---

If I do ssh -vv pi@192.168.1.100, I get this log:

```
thomas@externalPC:~/.ssh$ ssh -vv pi@192.168.1.100
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.100" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.100 [192.168.1.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: Found key in /home/thomas/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.1.100's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: Did you try the old password (`raspberry`) to make sure it didn't not get changed?  Also, if you use `ssh -vv pi@192.168.1.100` you will get a lot more verbose information that might explain explicitly what the issue is, or at least provide a clue you could cut n' paste in above.

Comment: Just updated and pasted above. Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: You could try taking the card out and looking in `/var/log/auth.log`.  This will show a record of successful and unsucessful login attempts by whatever means.  If the unsuccessful logins are shown there, this proves `sshd` is denying you from the pi and therefore most likely: A) You've done something odd with `sshd_config`; B) The password is not what you think it is.

Comment: The file '/var/log/auth.log' shows a lot of issues. If I grep the string "ssh", the most relevant message is "Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22". No other messages about trying to connect.

Comment: In fact, if I try to ssh within the raspberry (not from the external PC),  ssh pi@192.168.1.100, it works ok and it is logged in the '/var/log/auth.log' file.

Comment: Add some kind of mark to the file (the logger will not care if stuff has been added arbitrarily), put it back in the pi, try the remote login, take it out.  This is to double-check if its actually adding anything when you try to log in.  If it *isn't*, then there's definitely an issue with the sshd setup.  If it is, it may help clarify exactly what's up.

Answer (score 1):

From the original machine, change the password again (I'm assuming you can boot to desktop without asking for password).  But use `sudo` (changes to root) - to force a change without knowing the current password. Use **Command Terminal**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo passwd pi
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Then login from that machine back again (loopback) to test

```
$ ssh pi@localhost
Password: xxxxxx
```

If this works, proceed to the other machine - but make sure you've got the right IP address (there might be a duplicate IP around).